# Memory layout in BSS segment

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

In a 64-bit machine, I write a simple C program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello,world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then gcc hello.c -o hello, size hello, I got:

```
    text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
    1156        492      16    1664     680 hello
```

Next, I add a global int variable in the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int global;
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    printf("Hello,world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Again compile and size, I got:

```
    text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
    1156        492      24    1672     688 hello
```

So, the question is, bss segment has got an increment of 8 bytes, but why? There is only an int variable global added. That should be 4.

BTW, gcc version is 4.4.7

Comment: Probably metadata. How do you think the linker is supposed to resolve the name of a global?

Comment: I'd say it is adding padding.I notice that if you add another global, so there are two in total, the bss size stays the same, then you add another and it jumps by 8 again.

Comment: Yes, you are right ! But what is the purpose of this ? Why does not it simply jump 4 by 4?

Comment: <sarcasm>The detail that the machine is 64-bit (whatever that means) is more than enough to warrant a specific yes/no answer to this question... since it's impossible to run a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit machine!</sarcasm>

Answer (score 5):

The segment size is rounded up to the next multiple of 8, so that anything that follows it will be aligned on a 64 bit boundary. The startup routine that zeroes it will use 64 bit stores anyway.

Comment: When I define global with initialization, the data segment jumps by 4, not 8. Is data segment different from BSS in memory allocation?  I'm sorry I don't understand the internals.